# Can two clans be merged in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My friend and I have two separate clans, and we want to merge them. Is this possible?

Comment: I didn't understand the question.
Do you want to join 2 clans?

Comment: You can't merge two different clan. If you want to be together one of you have to quit and join another clan.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to make one clan then costumize it otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

No, merging is not possible. All the members will have to leave 1 clan and join the other clan.